# ``data.table`` object, nested into ``xgboost`` object, doesn't load when saved as ``.rda``

Tags: r, data.table, xgboost

Assume I have an `xgboost` model, which I want to store for later reuse. Additionally, I store additional information to the object for future convenience, one of which is the `data` clause, stored as a `data.table`, i.e.,

```
 stored_data <- as.data.table(data)
 model$data <- stored_data
```

Saving and loading the model works, i.e.,

```
 save(model, 'data/model.rda')
```

however, the `$data` is not retained after reattaching the object:

```
 load('data/model.rda')
 model$data
 R> NULL
```

On the other hand,

```
 model$data <- as.data.frame(stored_data)
```

appears to work, but it would be interesting to figure out what is the problem with `data.table` object (or `xgboost` object, not sure which causes the problem here).

**Side note:** I'm sticking to `.rda` files because I'm using them for lazy load into a package, i.e,

```
.onLoad <- function(lib, pkg){
  utils::data(model, package = pkg, envir = parent.env(environment()))
}
```

It would be nice to use `.rds` instead of `.rda`, but I'm not sure how would one do that.

**EDIT:**
What's weird, that it is null when calling from within a function. I.e., `model$data` returns a frame in the global environment, but when going to a `debugonce(a_function)`, from within debug `model$data` returns `NULL`. The model object is the same, I've checked with adding a timestamp to `comment(model)`.

Comment: You probably need a deep copy: `model$data <- copy(stored_data)` or just `model$data <- as.data.table(data)`.

Comment: I also noticed that with ``data.frame``, within debug, ``get("model")`` also emits the ``$data`` variable, while in clean environment it is there, suggesting it might have cached somewhere..?

Comment: @Roland thanks, I'll check.

Comment: i find quite often with my rda files, if i wrap the load with `get()` and assign to a variable it works, it is probably not the best method

Comment: @ChrisLittler @Roland What's weird, that it is null when calling from within a function. I.e., ``model$data`` returns a frame, ``debugonce(a_function)``, from within debug ``model$data`` returns ``NULL``. The model object is the same, I've checked with adding a timestamp to ``comment(model)``.

Comment: @ChrisLittler @Roland looks like the problem was with the naming of ``$data``.... Even though ``xgboost`` does not use this name for its object, any other variable name works... I guess I'm deleting this question. Thanks for ideas!